# Eval mode for Tensorflow Eager

Tags: python, tensorflow

I Pytorch there is this concept of [`eval()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.eval) mode which, when set, affect some layers of the model such as deactivating dropout.

I'm using Tensorflow 1.9 with eager/`tf.data.Dataset`/Keras model subclassing and I was wondering if there is an equivalent for it as I don't want to dropout/batchnorm during the validation or test phase.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Keras, there is a similar concept of [learning phase](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/learning_phase) that, if set to 1 (i.e. "test") via [`set_learning_phase`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/set_learning_phase), disable some layers such as dropout.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!